# Javascript microsecond timer differences between browsers?

Tags: javascript

In this jsFiddle I have some animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/p4u8tptj/

```
/*Square / Triangle Animations*/
var triangleWaiting;
posTriangle = height - 100;
triangleDir = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    if(triangleDir == 1 && posTriangle >= 0) --posTriangle;
    if(triangleDir == 0 && posTriangle <= height - 100) ++posTriangle;
    if(!triangleWaiting){
        if(posTriangle >= height - 100) triangleDir = 1;
    } else {
        if(cubeDir == 0) triangleDir = 1;
    }
    if(posTriangle <= 0) triangleDir = 0;
    triangle.style['margin-top'] = posTriangle+'px';
}, 1);

cubeDir = 0;
posCube = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    if(cubeDir == 1 && posCube <= height - 200) --posCube;
    if(cubeDir == 0 && posCube >= 0) ++posCube;
    if(posCube <= 0) cubeDir = 0;
    if(posCube >= height - 200)  cubeDir = 1;
    cube.style['margin-top'] = posCube+'px';
}, 6);

/*Correct for error*/
setInterval(function(){
    if(triangleDir == cubeDir){
        triangleWaiting = true;
    } 
}, 1);
```

Things move slightly slower in Safari, like somehow 1 microsecond is faster in Chrome.  What's going on?

Comment: Performance improvements on V8.

Comment: @DOCASAREL Wow, that much of a difference, huh.

Comment: Do you mean millisecond?

Comment: The [w3c specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html) has a few things to say. (1) The timeout is in milliseconds, not microseconds. (2) "Note: This API does not guarantee that timers will fire exactly on schedule." (3) "Optionally, wait a further user-agent defined length of time." (4) "If timeout is less than 10, then increase timeout to 10."

Comment: @RaymondChen—the version you quoted is dated 25 May 2011. Better to reference the "editor's draft", which is changed almost daily (the current version is dated today), see [*§7.4 Timers*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#timers) which has changed substantially from the 2011 draft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1ms timer is not given to be exactly 1ms. The browser can make it as long as it likes. Either longer or shorter. You should measure and correct for the delta T between callbacks. So you run the animation forward an amount depending on how much time has past.

Comment: Nor does the `1` argument to `setInterval` mean `1ms`. It means some point in the future no less than 1ms away, when the browser is done with whatever else it might happen to working on at the time, including rendering, garbage collection, event handling, you name it.

Comment: @torazaburo Actually, by specification, "1" means "some point in the future no less than *ten* ms away."

Comment: @RaymondChen—HTML5 documents *what browsers do* as much as *what they **should** do*, but doesn't tell you which one. *setTimeout* wasn't "standardised" until HTML5, so what you see is probably the result of a compromise of what various browsers were doing until recently (noting that big browser vendors have a very strong influence on the specification). And while HTML5 is a specification, it isn't (and is likely to never be) a standard.